# Split Comma delimited String excluding those in brackets within the brackets

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have the following String to be split:

**Given String:**

```
[PSR__123456_A,[AgrID=123456,PoolID=A],,Auto,Bank,0,0],[PSR__123456_A,[AgrID=123456,PoolID=A],,Auto,Bank,0,0],[PSR_Net__123456_A,[AgrID=123456,PoolID=A],,Suppress_Collateral,Bank,0,0]
```

**Expected Results: (3 elements)**

```
[PSR__123456_A,[AgrID=123456,PoolID=A],,Auto,Bank,0,0]
[PSR__123456_A,[AgrID=123456,PoolID=A],,Auto,Bank,0,0]
[PSR_Net__123456_A,[AgrID=123456,PoolID=A],,Suppress_Collateral,Bank,0,0]
```

I have tried the following regular expressions to parse/split the above string:

```
",(?![^[]*[]])" or ",(?=(((?!]).)*\[)|[^\[\]]*$)"
```

but still I cannot achieve the expected results, but rather it gives me the following results (6 elements) instead:

```
[PSR__123456_A
[AgrID=123456,PoolID=A],,Auto,Bank,0,0]
[PSR__123456_A
[AgrID=123456,PoolID=A],,Auto,Bank,0,0]
[PSR_Net__123456_A
[AgrID=123456,PoolID=A],,Suppress_Collateral,Bank,0,0]
```

Is there a way to do this in Java (RegEx) without splitting the String character by character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to select the comma when and what is at the right should be 2 times an opening and 2 times a closing square bracket, you might use:

```
,(?=\[[^[]*\[[^[]*\][^]]*\])
```

In Java:

```
String regex = ",(?=\\[[^\\[]*\\[[^\\[]*\\][^]]*\\])";
```

See the [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QPhAAb/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/9TcQyp)

That will match:

- `,` Match comma
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `\[[^[]*\[[^[]*\][^]]+\]` matches:
  - `\[` Match `[`
  - `[^[]*` Negated character class not matching `[`
  - `\[` Match `[`
  - `[^[]*` Negated character class not matching `[`
  - `\]` Match `]`
  - `[^]]*` Negated character class not matching `]`
  - `\]` Match `]`
- `)` Close positive lookahead

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your first elements start with `[PSR`, then you can use a regex with positive lookahead like this:

```
,(?=\[PSR)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/5AbaTe/1)**

With `\n` as replacement string

Update: as **[Manish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/913369/manish)** described in his comment, you can actually use `],[` with `]\n[` as replacement string

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/5AbaTe/2)**

Comment: _If_ the first element indeed always has the same prefix.

Comment: @FedericoPiazza thanks for that, however, all the string elements vary except the pattern of a string enclosed in square brackets :-)

Comment: @Jown can you describe the first pattern? Does it have always `__` or any type of pattern?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/5AbaTe/2 , does not have dependency on starting characters

Comment: @Manish lol I didn't see that. Updated the answer, thanks for the comment